# L'orthographe de « séisme » et de « sismique, sismographe, etc »

Tags: orthographe, écriture

Pourquoi les mots **séisme** et **sismique** s’écrivent différemment ?
Tous les deux viennent du mot grec [seismos](https://emcitv.com/bible/strong-biblique-grec-seismos-4578.html). Séisme a gardé le e du grec ; sismique pas (ainsi que tous les autres mots de la même famille).

Selon [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/sismique)

> SISMIQUE [si-smi-k'] adj.  Terme de physique. Qui est relatif aux
>   tremblements de terre.  Mouvement sismique, mouvement vibratoire
>   donnant lieu aux tremblements de terre, et consistant en des
>   oscillations verticales, horizontales ou circulaires. 
>   ÉTYMOLOGIE Du grec, succussion. Il ne faut pas
>   écrire seismique, la diphtongue grecque se rendant par i.

Selon [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/s%C3%A9isme/71854/difficulte)

> ORTHOGRAPHE
>   Séisme est la seule orthographe admise. En revanche, les
>   autres mots de la même famille prennent de préférence la forme *sism- :*
>   *sismal, sismicité, sismique, sismographe, sismologie* (plutôt que
>   *séismal, séismicité, séismique, séismographe, séismologie*). →
>   sismique. 
>   REMARQUE
>   Naguère critiquée (la diphtongue *ei* du grec
>   *seismos* devrait en toute rigueur être transcrite *i*, comme dans
>   *liturgie*, issu de *leitourgia*), la forme *séisme* est entrée dans
>   l'usage.

En outre même dans l'écriture de séisme, je me demande pour quelle raison un accent aigu apparaît sur *e* de la diphtongue *ei* ?

Comment: Apparemment il n'y a pas de diphtongues en français; la prononciation de « ei » exige deux sons, e et i ou é et i. https://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/phonetique-2/tableau-des-sons-du-francais.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il semble qu’il existe des doublons pour [la plupart](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/sismo-) des termes reliés. Dans le domaine des sciences de la Terre :

- sismal, séismal
- sismogénique, séismogénique
- sismomètre, séismomètre
- sismométrique, séismométrique
- sismoscope, séismoscope
- sismotectonique, séismotectonique

Et même en médecine :

- sismothérapie, séismothérapie

Par contre, il y a seulement ***séisme***.

La mention du TLFi dans la section étymologie est éclairante à ce sujet, à la fois pour la différence habituelle de traitement entre séisme et ses dérivés, et le traitement habituel de la diphtongue grecque :

> Les 2 formes *sism-* et *séism-* sont bien attestées à la fois par la documentation et dans les dictionnaires. Néanmoins, la diphtongue grecque *ei* étant habituellement rendue par *i* en français (Littré en fait déjà la remarque), l'Académie des Sciences a décidé en mars 1967 d’adopter la forme *sism-* pour tous les dérivés de *séisme*, tout en conservant l'orthographe de *séisme*, consacrée par l'usage. La forme *sism-* était déjà largement utilisée par les auteurs littéraires avant cette date tandis que les spécialistes semblaient préférer la forme *séism-*. On la relève encore chez certains de ces derniers, après 1967 (par exemple dans Géophys., 1971 [Encyclopédie de la Pléiade], J.-P. Rothé, Séismes et volcans, Paris, P.U.F., 1977).

Quant à la forme avec accent aigu, il ne faut pas oublier qu’il existe un digramme *ei* en français, dont la prononciation habituelle est [ɛ]. Il convient donc de marquer la séparation de ces deux lettres pour la diphtongue. Un tréma sur le *i* aurait probablement engendré quelque chose comme [sɛism(ə)] ou [sɛjsm(ə)], mais les habitudes de la langue ont probablement préféré l’accent aigu sur le *e*, qui a engendré un [seism(ə)] plus près des attentes des usagers. Le son [e] est d’ailleurs plus proche de [i] que le son [ɛ].

Comment: Les formes en éi étaient probablement critiquée parce que le ει de la source grecque de séisme n'a jamais représenté qu'une voyelle longue et que la version en deux syllabes découle d'une lecture naïve de la transcription en français du grec. La tradition d'adaptation de ει en "i" date du latin classique et reflète la prononciation grecque contemporaine, avec un i long. Ironiquement l'orthographe "seisme" proposée dans la question aurait probablement conduit le français de Belgique à prononcer le mot /sɛ:zm/ ou /se:zm/, avec une voyelle proche de celle qu'il avait en grec classique (/e:/)